# Convert meta tiles names to an x,y,z notation in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

Using `mod_tile/renderd` to serve OpenStreetMap tiles, I would like to list all tiles already generated in the cache but with an `z, x, y` notation. Currently, I only get paths for my list of `*.meta` files

```
cd /var/lib/mod_tile/ && find `pwd` -name '*.meta' |sed -e 's/\/var\/lib\/mod_tile\/default\///g' | sed -e 's/\.meta//g'
```

The remaining problem is to convert meta tiles paths to the `z, x, y` notation.

I already tried to:

- find an existing Python function using a search engine
- to reverse the logic of function [`xyz_to_meta`](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/blob/master/renderd.py#L280) that do the opposite  (in the Github `mod_tile` repository) but I'm really bad at bit manipulation (e.g [the definition of the meta tiles pattern](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/blob/master/readme.txt#L62) )
- convert [this available C code](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/blob/6b9611aaf763f4f776d1fd363433aac7e25cb34b/extra/meta2tile.c#L44) to Python

Python or Bash answers are preferred because I don't want to add more packages on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, I was able to make the conversion from the C code from `meta2tile.c` mentioned in my question. I didn't try to make any input validation so add a try/except if you want more control on the input.

```py
import io
import os
from pathlib import Path

METATILE = 8

XYs = []
for i in range(0,METATILE):
    for j in range(0,METATILE):
        XYs.append([i, j])

def list_existing_tiles_in_meta(directory='/var/lib/mod_tile/', map='default'):
    """
    List tiles using x,yz scheme from meta file directory
    """
    # List available meta tiles and write the stdout to "file"
    p = Path(os.path.join(directory, map))
    metas = [str(meta.relative_to(p)).replace('.meta', '') for meta in p.rglob('*.meta')]
    with io.open('/tmp/list_tiles.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
        for meta in metas:
            outfile.write('\n'.join(meta_to_xyz_all(*meta_to_xyz(meta))) + '\n')

def meta_to_xyz(pattern_meta_with_zoom='6/0/0/0/50/136'):
    """
    Convert meta tiles to z x y scheme for mod_tile
    Author: Thomas Gratier based on Frederik Ramm C code from meta2tile.c from mod_tile
    License: GPL
    """
    x, y = 0, 0
    path_elements = [int(i) for i in pattern_meta_with_zoom.split('/')]
    z = path_elements.pop(0)
    for i in path_elements:
        x <<= 4
        y <<= 4
        x |= (i & 0xf0) >> 4
        y |= (i & 0x0f)
    return z, x, y

def meta_to_xyz_all(z, x, y):
    tiles_xyz = ['/'.join([str(z), str(x + mx), str(y + my)]) for (mx, my) in XYs]
    return tiles_xyz

# Try

# Previous function call
print(meta_to_xyz('6/0/0/0/34/0'))
# Function that return a list of tiles for a meta tile
print(meta_to_xyz_all(*meta_to_xyz('6/0/0/0/34/0')))
```

**Edit**: I've added more. Although I've made a port of an existing code, it was incomplete. A meta file contains more than one png file content (e.g https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Meta_tiles). So providing a meta reference, it should return more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

```
def meta_to_xyz(pattern_meta_with_zoom='6/0/0/0/50/136'):
    """
    Convert meta tiles to z x y scheme for mod_tile
    Author: Thomas Gratier based on Frederik Ramm C code from meta2tile.c from mod_tile
    License: GPL
    """
    x, y = 0, 0
    path_elements = [int(i) for i in pattern_meta_with_zoom.split('/')]
    z = path_elements.pop(0)
    for i in path_elements:
        x <<= 4
        y <<= 4
        x |= (i & 0xf0) >> 4
        y |= (i & 0x0f)
    return z, x, y


def xyz_to_meta(pattern_xyz='12/981/1535'):
    """
    Convert meta tiles to z x y scheme for mod_tile
    Author: Chad Nelson based on reverse operation of Thomas Gratier's meta_to_xyz
    License: GPL, LGPL, WTFPL
    """
    path_elements = pattern_xyz.split('/')
    path_elements = map(int, path_elements)
    z = path_elements[0]
    x = path_elements[1]
    y = path_elements[2]
    meta_path = list([z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    for i in range(5, 1, -1):
        meta_path[i] = ((x & 0x0f) << 4) | (y & 0x0f)
        x >>= 4
        y >>= 4

    return meta_path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print meta_to_xyz('6/0/0/0/50/136')
    print xyz_to_meta('6/56/40')
```